# My domain name no longer works after being transferred. How can I troubleshoot?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registration

I recently transferred my domain (sniphq.com) from MyDomain to DreamHost. Today, for some reason, I can't get to sniphq.com at all. When I log into DreamHost, there doesn't appear to be any way to do anything like change the IP where my domain is pointed like I could do with MyDomain, which is super awesome.

I know it's not the server itself because I can go to the server's IP and my app works just fine.

Any advice on what I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Contact your hosting provider.

Comment: I see PIPA must have started. NOO!  [STOP SOPA & PIPA!]

Comment: Why is this off topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your ns records are pointing to Dreamhost, as they should be:

```
$ whois sniphq.com
  <snip>
  ns1.dreamhost.com
  ns2.dreamhost.com
  ns3.dreamhost.com
```

However, it doesn't look like any zones have been created at Dreamhost for your domain:

```
$ dig @ns1.dreamhost.com sniphq.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> @ns1.dreamhost.com sniphq.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 4979
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sniphq.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 101 msec
;; SERVER: 66.33.206.206#53(66.33.206.206)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 18 15:01:58 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 28
```

You need to create a DNS zone for your domain. You'll need to refer to Dreamhost's documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Dreamhost's DNS servers are not serving your domain. Check in your domain control panel to make sure they know they're supposed to be providing it DNS.

```
Domain servers in listed order:
  ns1.dreamhost.com
  ns2.dreamhost.com
  ns3.dreamhost.com

Server:         ns1.dreamhost.com
Address:        66.33.206.206#53
** server can't find sniphq.com: SERVFAIL

Server:         ns2.dreamhost.com
Address:        208.96.10.221#53
** server can't find sniphq.com: SERVFAIL

Server:         ns3.dreamhost.com
Address:        66.33.216.216#53
** server can't find sniphq.com: SERVFAIL
```